# WooCommerce asking to confirm email on checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce asking to confirm email on checkout page but there is no initial field to enter the email address. Any idea where I need to look? I am kind of new to Woo.

[image]

Comment: I would start with disabling all other plugins and reverting to Twenty Sixteen. I don't believe this is core WooCommerce behavior, so you need to find what is causing it.

Comment: Yep, I actually went and reordered the fields in the plugin Woocommerce Poor Guys Swiss Army Knife within Woocommerce Checkout Billing Section. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Reorder the fields in the plugin Woocommerce Poor Guys Swiss Army Knife and specifically within Woocommerce Checkout Billing Section. Keep the email fields next to each other. That worked for me.